# Canvas and Save for web colors mismatch in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-profile

The colors of my Photoshop canvas are not the same as my Save-to-Web output.

For example, #0000FF:
  [image: 00F sample]

I know there is something set wrong in the color profiles, but I can't figure out what is is.

The document is:
`sRGB IEC61966-2.1`

My settings are:
`RGB: sRGB IEC61966-2.1`

Comment: post full screen of save for web and device part, there are some option in right hand side, just curious to see, might be something is there

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this problem with any usual settings. It's hard to tell from your screenshot exactly what's going on, since neither of those colors is #0000ff. The canvas color looks quite wrong, however, so I suspect either color proofing (`View > Proof Colors` or Ctl-Y) is turned on, or you need to reset your preferences (Ctl-Alt-Shift while the program is loading).

Try those and see if the problem resolves.